# How to take mysql database backup by using java?

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to take mysql database backup by using following code but I am getting exception like below when I run the program. Plz can anyone plz help out to solve this problem.

**Java Code:**

```
        String path = "D:/databasbac.sql";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";
        String dbname = "ranjith";
        String executeCmd = "<Path to MySQL>/bin/mysqldump -u " + username + " -p" + password + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbname + " -r " + path;
        Process runtimeProcess;
        try {
//            System.out.println(executeCmd);//this out put works in mysql shell
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", executeCmd });
//            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup created successfully");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Exception is not coming now but the the sop is printing like the could not create the backup

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues:

1. Provide a full path to `mysqldump.exe` (e.g. `C:\Program Files\MySQL\bin\mysqldump.exe`)
2. `-p` parameter without a password value forces mysqldump to prompt for it. And you don't want it since you running it in a batch mode. Therefore either provide a password `-p"your password"` or better (and more secure) use an option file to avoid giving the password on the command line. Read more on this [End-User Guidelines for Password Security](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-security-user.html)

Comment: I have updated my answer can u plz check and tell me