# Mysql database backup by using java

Tags: java, mysql

I am going to take database backup by using java code.This code is excuting fine but I am getting    **int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();** This method calling is returning the integer as 1. So finally I am getting the message as could not create backup as sop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path = "D:/databasebackup/databasbac.sql";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";
        String dbname = "rac";
        String executeCmd = "<Path to MySQL>/bin/mysqldump -u " + username + " -p" + password + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbname + " -r " + path;
        Process runtimeProcess;
        try {
//            System.out.println(executeCmd);//this out put works in mysql shell
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", executeCmd });
            System.out.println(executeCmd);
//            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
            System.out.println("processComplete"+processComplete);
            if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup created successfully");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: try to read process's error stream for possible failures

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(executeCmd);`? Did you try to execute this exact command on the command line?

Comment: This what I am getting <Path to MySQL>/bin/mysqldump -u root -p --add-drop-database -B rac -r D:/databasebackup/databasbac.sql

Comment: What is this mean `This code is excuting fine `  is this code is able to create a backup ? or Not ? If it is may your choice of checking is wrong

Comment: Its not creating backup file but i am not getting any exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take mysql database backup by using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772852/how-to-take-mysql-database-backup-by-using-java)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar problem in database backup from MYSQL through JDBC. So I ran the below code.

```
String path = C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump

String command= "cmd.exe /c "
                    + "\"\""+path+"\"  "
                    + " --user="+UserInputs.getDbUserName()
                    + " --password="+UserInputs.getDbPassword()
                    + " --host="+UserInputs.getDbConnectionIP()
                    + " --protocol=tcp "
                    + " --port="+UserInputs.getDbConnectionPort()
                    + " --default-character-set=utf8 "
                    + " --single-transaction=TRUE "
                    + " --routines "
                    + " --events "
                    + "\""+UserInputs.getDbName()
                    +"\" "
                    + ">"
                    + " \""
                    + "D:\\MY DATA\\DB_Backup.sql"
                    + "\""
                    + " \"";

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(command);
```

In case password is blank remove the --password line.
This will create your database backup.

In case you are running this on LINUX replace

```
cmd.exe /c
```

by

```
/bin/sh -c
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try out my code for backup the database using java. It works well for me.

```
try {

     String filename = null;

     FileChooser.setVisible(true);

     int result = FileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

     if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            filename = FileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString().concat(".sql");

            File file = new File(filename);

            if (file.exists()) {
                    Object option[] = {"Sim", "Nao"};

                    int opcao = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "aaa", "bbbb", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, option, option[0]);

                    if (opcao == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                             Runtime backup = Runtime.getRuntime();
                             backup.exec("C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.17\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -v -v -v --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --protocol=tcp --force --allow-keywords --compress --add-drop-table --result-file=" + filename + " --databases GIVE YOUR DATABSE NAME");
                             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup succesfully");
                    } else {
                         FileChooserActionPerformed(evt);
                    }
           } else {
                 Runtime backup = Runtime.getRuntime();
                 backup.exec("C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.17\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -v -v -v --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --protocol=tcp --force --allow-keywords --compress --add-drop-table --result-file=" + filename + " --databases GIVE YOUR DATABASE NAME");
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup succesfully");
           }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Error.!", 2);
}
```

And this is the DbOperation class That i have written.

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbOperation {
       String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/give your database name";
       String username = "your username";
       String password = "your password";
       Connection con = null;
       PreparedStatement pst = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;

       public Connection backupDB(){
              try{
                  con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
              }catch(SQLException e){
                  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
              }
       return con;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.exitValue();
```

[runtime info](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html)

Hope this helps